# git repo with submodules: fork and create your own branch

Tags: git, github, git-branch, git-submodules, git-fork

I am having issues working with git submodules. I want to know a clean way of doing the following.

I want to fork a git repository which has submodules and then I want to create my own branch for each of the submodule and work on that. Can anyone tell a clean way of doing this? One way that I know is to basically fork each submodule separately, set the upstream and create your own branch. But this process is a little painful if there are a lot of submodules. Also as in general for the git repos with submodule a particular commit point in the submodule is tracked. If I create my own fork for each submodule it will become hard to be in sync with the original git repo.

Any suggestions ?

Thanks.

Comment: do you really plan to develop stuff in all those submodules? You could not fork them, instead just using the upstream's ones.

Comment: Yes, I will be using almost all of those submodules.